# Quick print to wrong printer. How to change?

Tags: windows-7, printing, printer, network-printer, microsoft-infopath

I work with a user who's work flow includes opening an InfoPath 2013 form, making a change, print, and repeat. Ever since a new printer was installed InfoPath quick print still goes to the old printer even though the new one is set to default in windows 7. We've removed the old printer from windows and quick print will select the new printer until the old printer get's automatically mapped from group policy. It seems as long as the old printer is mapped InfoPath will only default to that one.

The question is, how do I change which printer InfoPath quick prints to by default? Where should I look to see where that setting is stored?

Thanks in an advance for any input.

Comment: Are you sure GP isn't also setting the old printer as Default when added (you may have to hit "refresh" on the "Devices and Printers" window to make the change visible)?

Comment: The group policy adds printers based on department. That department has 3 printers all mapped through GP, non to be set as default.

Comment: InfoPath is an MS program, so it should depend on Windows to supply the printer, so that's pretty strange if it's picking a printer that isn't set as the Windows default (which is what Quick Print will try to use)...  Do other (MS) programs always quick-print to the expected printer?

Comment: Other MS Office programs will quick print to the new printer. We thought because the forms are opened through SharePoint it could be an IE setting retaining that but resetting IE settings did not resolve it.

Comment: If you create a new basic InfoPath file (local to the computer) and try to print it, does it behave the same way?